# Meaning of come on down to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "come on down to someplace" mean?

I know the meaning of "come down to someplace". [It means traveling to the south to reach that specific place.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-down)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The particular exhortation ***Come on down to** [some commercial establishment]* is effectively a "set phrase" in advertising voiceovers ("Come on down to our shop / entertainment centre / etc."). The specific preposition ***down*** has no "directional / locational" significance, but it's always included. The same applies to ***on***. Syntactically, only one preposition is needed in "Come **to** our shop", but I think the advertising copywriters assume including ***...on down...*** makes the invitation somehow more "welcoming" and/or implies it's not far to go.

Comment: It does not mean "go south". It is a friendly way of inviting someone to go somewhere. Example: "Why don't y'all come on down to our place after work?"

Comment: @FeliniusRex To clarify, it doesn't (necessarily) mean go south in this context. But yes, "up" and "down" are often used with north and south (see the linked Cambridge dictionary entry); "We went up to Vermont"/"down to Florida for the holidays." If your grandma in Florida invited you to "come on down to my place," then both usages would be conflated.

Comment: @Andy It does not definitively, always mean "go south".